# Как получить текст определенной строки в TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-textview

Есть TextView. Допустим нам нужно получить текст третьей строки этого TextView. Как это можно риализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Скопитырено [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273546/4711135)

Вы можете использовать `textView.getLayout().getLineStart(int line)` и `getLineEnd` для задания границ текста, который надо получить.

Затем просто `textView.getText().substring(start, end)`, или `textView.getText().subSequence(start, end)` если вы применяете Spannables для форматирования и так далее.

Соответственно, чтобы получить третью строку надо:

```
int line = 3;
int start = textView.getLayout().getLineStart(line);
int end = textView.getLayout().getLineStart(line);

String s = textView.getText().toString().substring(start, end);
```

или

```
String s = textView.getText().subSequence(start, end);
```

Comment: студия выделяет красным substarting. При наведении пишет cannot resolve method 'substring(int,int)'. Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: @rfvgy1 тогда textView.getText().subSequence(start, end)

Comment: почему-то что бы ни было в textview переменная s всегда = null. Вот текст textview "ss\nsd". Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: @rfvgy1 сколько всего строк в textView? Если вот столько  `"ss\nsd"`, то тут всего две 1-ая `ss` 2-ая `sd`, или, если одна, в таком случае line = 3 всегда будет возвращать `null`. Делайте проверку, чтобы line был не больше `textView.getLineCount() -1`

Comment: у меня line=0 но переменная s все равно = null

Comment: @rfvgy1 не знаю, чудеса. А что выводит `textView.getText().toString();`?

Comment: я сделал так `Toast.makeText(this, textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` и отобразился тост в две строки - на первой ss на второй sd

Comment: @rfvgy1 уже хорошо, а теперь например `textView.getText().subSequence(0, 0)`, или `textView.getText().subSequence(1, 1)` что выведет?

Comment: в обоих случаях пустой тост. Как решить?

Comment: @rfvgy1 только что у себя проверил - все работает, обеими способами

Comment: отправте пожалуйста весь свой void

Comment: @rfvgy1 тоже самое, что и у вас. Вплоть до названия переменных. Ну слушайте, по ссылке на англоязычном so точно также и работает

Comment: у вас так? `public void cll(View v) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        int line = 0;
        int start = textView.getLayout().getLineStart(line);
        int end = textView.getLayout().getLineStart(line);
        String s = (String) textView.getText().subSequence(start, end);
        Toast.makeText(this, textView.getText().subSequence(0, 0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }`

Comment: @rfvgy1 `s=subSequence(start, end).toString(); ` `Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: по прежнему безрезультатно: `public void cll(View v) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        int line = 0;
        int start = textView.getLayout().getLineStart(line);
        int end = textView.getLayout().getLineStart(line);
        String s = textView.getText().subSequence(start, end).toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }`

Comment: @rfvgy1 попробуйте забрать весь текст https://stackoverflow.com/a/8798989/4711135

Comment: я разобрался, subSequence берет не строки, а символы, тоесть в моем случае subSequence(0, 1) будет возвращать "s". Но ответ на свой вопрос я так и не нашел

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался.
Вот решение:

```
    String Str = new String("ss\nsd");

      for (String retval : Str.split("\n")) {
         System.out.println(retval);
}
```